# I want to get day either is today or yesterday on the basis of miliseconds time i get

Tags: java, datetime, date-comparison

I have to return the string today and yesterday.  The milliseconds I got from a function, so what have I got to do? I tried a lot.

```
    if((data.getStartTimeMilli()-86400000) < data.getStartTimeMilli())
    {
        return "Today";
    }
    else 
    {
        return "Yesterday";
    }
```

But it will return only today.
Two millisecond values I pass in function, one is `startdatemili` and `enddatemili`.
It’s a range of dates.

Comment: (data.getStartTimeMilli()-86400000) < data.getStartTimeMilli() always returns true!

Comment: Assuming 86400000 is 24 hours in milliseconds, that might not work.  You'll get whether something was 24 hours ago, but yesterday usually means before midnight.  So if you checked this at 12:01 am, everything that is actually yesterday would be flagged as "today" unless it was within a minute of midnight yesterday.

Comment: Isn’t it a simple typo? Did you mean `if (data.getEndTimeMilli() - 86_400_000 < data.getStartTimeMilli())` (using both end and start instead of start both times)?

Comment: Also your requirements aren’t that clear. You may want to give example millisecond values, one example where you expect `Today` and another example where you expect `Yesterday`. And explain the issue that @markspace rises because I agree that it isn’t clear why you would only want `Yesterday` for something that is strictly longer than 24 hours ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As menthioned in the comment, usually `today` does not mean `24` hours ago.

Suppose now is `2018-10-06 15:20`, `2018-10-06 00:01` should be considered as `today`, while `2018-10-05 23:59` is `yesterday`, though thay are both within `24` hours.

---

This solution works on above assumption.

Get the start millis of today:

```
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.now();
zonedDateTime = zonedDateTime.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS);

long millis = zonedDateTime.toInstant().toEpochMilli();
```

then compare with it:

```
if((data.getStartTimeMilli() > millis) {
    return "Today";
} else
    return "Yesterday";
}
```

But be careful, when the start milli is before `today`, does not mean it is `yesterday`, it might be some day earlier.

---

If you do want to use `24 hours` to limit today:

```
Instant instant = Instant.now().minusMillis(86400000);
long millis = instant.toEpochMilli();
```

Answer (score 2):

Many ways to find it out.

Using simple Java API:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
 c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
 c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
 c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
 c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
 // Assuming we are expecting milliseconds from today or yesterday only.
 if(( System.currentTimeMillis() - c.getTimeInMillis()) > 0 )
        {
            return "Today";
        }
        else 
        {
            return "Yesterday";
        }
```